# Custom Join Clause For Hibernate Many To One

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to tailor the query that hibernate executes when retrieving associations for a given entity? More specifically I would like to add an extra condition to a join clause to cater for a design flaw in a legacy database I am working with.

The problem I am facing is below. The primary key for **table b** consists of 2 fields, a category `id` and a `value_id`. However in **table A** I only have the `value_id` stored and it is assumed that the category id is hard coded:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class A {
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
   private B b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class B {
   @Id
   private int id;
}
```

When querying for instances of A, hibernate generates the following join clause :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
  ON a_.b_id = b_.value_id
```

Whereas they query I require it to execute is :

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a a LEFT OUTER JOIN table_b b
  ON a_.b_id = b_.value_id
 AND b.category_id = 2
```

I know that I could use a view to work around this problem, however it would require me to create around 70 views which I would like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It wasn't the prettiest solution, but the only one that worked.

Basically I had to do:

1. Simulate a Embbeded ID to class A
2. Make a Join between A -> B using the real key column and categoryId comparing to a formula

Like this:

Obs: I didn't test this code, just adapted from mine.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class A {
   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value={
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column=
                @JoinColumn(name="B_ID", referencedColumnName="B_ID")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=
                @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName="CATEGORY_ID", 
                        value = "(SELECT 2 from DUAL)"))}) //I am using Oracle
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
   private B b;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
class B {
   @Id
   private BId id;
}

@Embeddable
class BId{
    private int id;
    private Integer categoryId;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing something here, how is the `BId` class being used/referenced?

Comment: @Andrew you are right. I forgot to put BId as key to class B. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>(0);
```

on `class B` to get the join and a named query to get `category_id` (also in `class B`)

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "B.findByCategoryId", query = "SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.Id = :categoryId")
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the problem relates to a unidirectional relationship and as such the solution you suggested is not applicable. Is it not possible to use JoinColumnOrFormulas? I have tried with a combination of a JoinColumn to specify the relationship between the classes and a JoinFormula to specify the additional join criteria but this just results in an error.